# How to convert accountKeys returned from the getTransaction method to public keys?

Tags: transactions, account

Is there a way to convert all the account keys returned from the getTransaction RPC call into a readable address format. For context the first public key should be "H8sMJSCQxfKiFTCfDR3DUMLPwcRbM61LGFJ8N4dK3WjS" when I use something like the [solana beach api](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/V2261/solanabeach-backend_api/0.0.1#/Transaction/fetchTransactionByHash). Here is the code I am running: https://github.com/toshvelaga/solana-rpc/blob/main/getTx.js

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.toBase58()`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#toBase58) method on those keys.